# Fitting closed b-spline to 2D data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, bspline

I am trying to implement my own code in Matlab to fit a closed b-spline to a set of 2D data.

I have generated the 2D data in form of an ellipse and used De boor algorithm. The code does work fine when set up for open b-spline, but it got stuck with closed (periodic) b-spline.

Here are the steps:

1. Generate the ordered 2D data **C** [2xn] in form of a 2D ellipse
2. Generate the parameter vector **t** [nx1] as per the uniform spaced or the chord-length method.
3. Generate the knot vector **u** [m+dx1] (:# control points, d: b-spline order): a) Open b-spline: uniform-clamped method b) closed b-spline: uniform method

> ```
> function u = npa_contfit_genknot(t,d,nmp,opt,varargin)
>    switch opt
>       case 'uniform-clamped'
>          a = varargin{1}(1);
>          b = varargin{1}(2);
>          u = [a*ones(1,d),...
>                   a:(b-a)/(nmp-d):b,...
>                      b*ones(1,d)]';
>       case 'uniform'
>          a = varargin{1}(1);
>          b = varargin{1}(2);
>          u = linspace(a,b,nmp+d)';
>       case 'average'
>          u = conv(t, [zeros(1,d) ones(1,d)]/d, 'same');
>          u = [zeros(d,1);u(d+1:end-1);ones(d,1)];
>    end
> end
> ```

4. Estimate the b-spline blending function values for every generated parameter value from **t**. Store the result in matrix B [nxm].

Function to construct the b-spline basis matrix **B**:

> ```
> % de-boor algorithm
> B   = zeros(nmt_i,nmp); 
> for j=0:nmp-1
>    [b,px] = npa_contfit_bsplinebasis(j,d,u,t_i);
>     B(:,j+1) = b;
> end
> ```

Function to estimate the b-spline blending function values

> ```
> function [y,t] = npa_contfit_bsplinebasis(i,d,u,t)
>
>    y = bspline_basis_recur(i,d,u,t);
>
>    % nested function
>    function y = bspline_basis_recur(i,d,u,t)
>       y = zeros(size(t));
>       if d > 1
>           b = npa_contfit_bsplinebasis(i,d-1,u,t);
>           dn = t - u(i+1);
>           dd = u(i+d) - u(i+1);
>           if dd ~= 0  % indeterminate forms 0/0 are deemed to be zero
>               y = y + b.*(dn./dd);
>           end
>           b = npa_contfit_bsplinebasis(i+1,d-1,u,t);
>           dn = u(i+d+1) - t;
>           dd = u(i+d+1) - u(i+1+1);
>           if dd ~= 0
>               y = y + b.*(dn./dd);
>           end
>       elseif u(i+2) < u(end)  % treat last element of knot vector as a special case
>          y(u(i+1) <= t & t < u(i+2)) = 1;
>       else
>          y(u(i+1) <= t) = 1;
>       end
>    end % end
> end
> ```

5. Estimate and store the control point vectors **p** (in least square sense) in **P**

> `P = (pinv(B)*C')';`

6. In case of closed b-spline wrap the the control point vectors

> `P = [P(:,end-d+1:end),P(:,d+1:end-d)]`

The result for open b-spline set up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgvIl.jpg

The result for the closed (periodic) b-spline set up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBodq.jpg

Comment: The steps are not detailed enough to tell you something useful, but it just seems like step 5 (least square sense estimation of control points) failed. It just looks like a trivial error somewhere. If you can provide the code it would be easier. With only this I don't know what exactly you did in steps 3-5.

Comment: Hi  Trilarion, just update by the source codes.